# Find the pdf of $\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$, where $X_is$ are independent uniform [0,1] random variables.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

How do I find the pdf of $\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$, where $X_is$ are independent uniform [0,1] random variables.

I know  X~U[0,1], -ln(x) is exponential(1).
I also know the sum of two or more independent exponential random variable is gamma.

For $Y = \sum_{i=1}^n -ln(x_i)$, which is a gamma(n, 1), I found the pdf for Y is $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma (n)} y^{n-1} e^{-y} dy$$.

Let $Z = e^Y$

I am trying to the pdf for Z, what I found is $$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma (n)} ln(z)^{n-1} \frac{1}{z^2} dz$$, which does not look right to me.
Could someone check it?

Comment: See [this](http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~macpd/georgiou/ProductRVs%20revised.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the resource! The material is too math intensive

Comment: Can you rederive the result when $n=2$? (using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution) directly, for instance?) And for $n=3,4,...$ using the trick of taking the logarithm of the product, and computing the convolution of the pdfs of the logarithms of uniform r.v.'s?

Comment: Can you show me some steps?

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738797/is-the-distribution-of-a-product-of-m-iid-uniform-random-variables-really-log-no

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/659254/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Note that $-\log X_j$ has an exponential(1) distribution.

Step 2: Note that $\sum_{j=1}^n (-\log X_j)$ is a sum of iid random variables, so convolution results apply.

Step 3: Figure out the convolution for the exponential distribution, by looking it up, by using characteristic functions, or moment-generating functions, whichever you're familiar with.  You'll find $f_X(x)=x^{n-1} e^{-x} / (n-1)!$ as the density of $-\log Y$, which is a $\Gamma$ distribution.

Step 4: Transform this back to get something like $(-\log y)^{n-1}/(n-1)!$.

Note that for increasing $g$ (decreasing $g$ is analogous),
$$\Pr(Y\leq y)=\Pr(g(X)\leq y)=\Pr(X\leq g^{−1}(y))=F_X(g^{−1}(y)).$$

Now differentiate with respect to $z$ to get

$$
f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) g^{-1}\;'(y)= \frac{f_X(g^{-1}(y))}{g'(g^{-1}(y))}.
$$

In your case $g(x)=\exp(−x)$ which is decreasing in $x$ and hence you need to replace the denominator with $|g′(g^{−1}(y))|$.

So $g'(x)=-\exp(-x)$ and $g^{-1}(y)=-\log y$.

Comment: what is the " convolution results "?

Comment: Convolutions are standard results that give you the distribution of a sum of two or more iid random variables.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more explicit on step 3?

Comment: I know  X~U[0,1], -ln(x) is exponential(1).
I also know the sum of two or more independent exponential random variable is gamma. 


For $Y = \sum_{i=1}^n -ln(x_i)$, which is a gamma(n, 1), I found the pdf for Y is $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma (n)} y^{n-1} e^{-y} dy$$.

Let $Z = e^Y$

I am trying to the pdf for Z, what I found is $$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma (n)} ln(z)^{n-1} \frac{1}{z^2} dz$$, which does not look like your step 4 result...Could you see what I did wrong?

Comment: Don't integrate.  The density function is the integrand, not the integral.  Aside from that, I think it should be $Z=e^{-Y}$.  By the standard change of variable formula for density functions I get for $y= -\log z$ that $$y^{n-1} e^{-y} / (\Gamma(n) e^{-y}) = (-\log z)^{n-1}/(n-1)!$$  Hope this helps.

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with the change of variables, note that if $z=g(y)$ with $g$ differentiable with everywhere nonzero derivative, then $f_Z(z)= f_Y\bigl( g^{-1}(z) \bigr) / \bigl| g'\bigl( g^{-1}(z)\bigr) \bigr|$.

Comment: could you expand on what you said here?

Comment: Yes.  Note that for increasing $g$ (decreasing $g$ is analogous), $$\Pr(Z\leq z)=\Pr(g(Y)\leq z)=\Pr(Y\leq g^{-1}(z)) = F(g^{-1}(z)).$$  Now differentiate with respect to $z$ to get $f_Z(z) = f_Y(g^{-1}(z)) g^{-1}'(z)= f_Y(g^{-1}(z))/g'(g^{-1}(z))$.  In your case $g=\exp(-y)$ which is decreasing in $y$ and hence you need to replace the denominator with $|g'(g^{-1}(z))|$.

Comment: you could just revised your answer under step 4...so that I can make it my favor answer

Comment: I've done just that.

Comment: how do you make that to become $(-\log y)^{n-1}/(n-1)$?

Comment: fixed typo, grrr, thanks

Comment: just to confirm: $$\frac{f_Y (g^{-1}(z))}{g'(g^{-1}(z)} = (-\log y)^{n-1}/(n-1)!$$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: could you show the intermediate steps?

Comment: Just figure it out, what is the range for this pdf in this case, is it Z >0  because $e^{-Y} > 0$?

Answer (score 1):

An attempt:

For the case $n=2$, using directly the fact that (for $Y=X_1X_2$, where $X_1,X_2\sim\operatorname{Unif}([0,1])$ are independent)
$$
\forall z\in[0,1],\quad f_Y(z)=\int_0^1 f_{X_1}(x)f_{X_2}\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)\frac{dx}{x}
$$
you get that for all $z\in(0,1]$
$$
f_Y(z)=\int_0^1 1\cdot \mathbb{1}_{\{\frac{z}{x}\in[0,1]\}}\frac{dx}{x} = \int_z^1 \frac{dx}{x} = \ln\frac{1}{z}
$$

For the general case, you can apply the trick of taking the logarithm of $Y=\prod_{k=1}^n X_k$, i.e. consider $Z\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \ln Y = \sum_{k=1}^n \ln X_k = \sum_{k=1}^n Z_k$ for $Z_k\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \ln X_k$, so that for all $z\in(-\infty,0]$
$$
f_Z(z)=(f_{X_1}\ast\cdot\ast f_{X_k})(z) = (f_{X_1}\ast\cdot\ast f_{X_1})(z)
$$
where $\ast$ is the convolution operator and
$$
\begin{align*}
f_{X_1}(x) &= \frac{d}{dx}\int_{-\infty}^x \mathbb{P}\left\{\ln X_1 \in dt\right\} = \frac{d}{dx} \mathbb{P}\left\{\ln X_1 \leq x\right\}= \frac{d}{dx} \mathbb{P}\left\{X_1 \leq e^x\right\}\\
&= \frac{d}{dx}\mathbb{P}\left\{X_1 \leq e^x\right\}= \frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x
\end{align*}
$$
(caveat: I haven't carefully checked my calculations) Once (after a lot of fun) you figure $f_Z$, you can go back to $f_Y$ by a similar process (using the cdf of $f_Z$, etc).

Comment: I just realized If X~U[0,1], -ln(x) is exponential(1)...Does this help reduce the work?

Comment: This is essentially what the last computation above shows (the one ending with $e^x$).

Comment: In the second line, how did you change the lower bound of the integral from $0$ to $z$?

Comment: The indicator $\mathbb{1}_{\frac{z}{x}\in[0,1]}$  is zero if $0 < x < z$.

Comment: That was helpful, thanks. I think I found my mistake: $\frac{z}{x}$ is $z$ divided by $x$, not $z|x$, correct? My prof sometimes writes $\frac{X}{Y}$ to show $X$ given $Y$ for random variables, but in this case the simple arithmetic division caught me off guard.

Comment: Yes, that's a honest-to-goodness division.