# Find the bias for the Maximum-likelihood estimator

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample from the pdf $$f(x|\theta) = \theta x^{\theta-1} , 0 \leq x \leq 1, \theta >0.$$

I found the Maximum-likelihood estimator of $\theta$ is $$\hat{\theta} = \frac{-n}{\sum_{i=1}^N \ln(X_i)}.$$ Can anyone confirm that this is right?

Then, I want to determine whether $\hat{\theta}$ has bias.
My approach is to calculate 
${\bf E}[\hat{\theta}] = {\bf E}\left[\frac{-n}{\sum_{i=1}^N \ln(X_i)}\right]$...Then I am stuck. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got the right answer for the MLE.  To find the expectation of $\hat{\theta}$, it will help to first find the distribution of the transformation $Y=-\log(X_i)$. It's a well known distribution, and so will be $-\sum \log(X_i)$ as well as  $-1/\sum \log(X_i)$.

You have already found that the distribution of $Y_i=-\log(X_i)$ is exponential($1/\theta$).

According to section 4.2 of Pitman, "Probability", the sum of n iid exponential($1/\theta$) distributions is gamma(n, $1/\theta$).  Thus, Z =$\sum Y_i=-\sum \log(X_i)$ is distributed gamma(n,$1/\theta$) where the pdf of Z is

$\dfrac{\theta^n}{\Gamma(n)}z^{n-1}e^{-z\theta}$ with mean $E(Z)=n/\theta$.

Notice that since a pdf must integrate to 1, it is straightforward to show

$\int_0^{\infty}z^{n-1}e^{-z\theta}dz=\dfrac{\Gamma(n)}{\theta^n}$. Call this result 1.

This will be useful in the following step to find $E(1/Z)$.

$E(1/Z) = \int_0^{\infty}1/z\dfrac{\theta^n}{\Gamma(n)}z^{n-1}e^{-z\theta}dz$

$= \dfrac{\theta^n}{\Gamma(n)} \int_0^{\infty}z^{(n-1)-1}e^{-z\theta}$

$= \dfrac{\theta^n}{\Gamma(n)}\dfrac{\Gamma(n-1)}{\theta^{n-1}}$ by result 1.

$=\dfrac{\theta\Gamma(n-1)}{\Gamma(n)}$

Now, according to Casella and Berger, Statistical Inference pg 99, a useful property of the gamma function is that

$\Gamma(\alpha+1)=\alpha\Gamma(\alpha)$, thus

$\Gamma(n)=\Gamma((n-1)+1) = (n-1)\Gamma(n-1)$ and

$E(1/Z) = \dfrac{\theta\Gamma(n-1)}{\Gamma(n)} =\dfrac{\theta\Gamma(n-1)}{(n-1)\Gamma(n-1)}= \theta/(n-1) $

It's now straightforward to find $E(n/Z) = n*E(1/Z) = n\theta/(n-1)  $.

Comment: I found that $log(X_i)$ has an exponential distribution with mean $1/\theta$. How does this help?

Comment: Do you know what the distribution is of a sum of exponential distributions?

Comment: is it going to be gamma distribution?

Comment: I have also showed that $2\theta \sum_{i=1}^n log(X_i)$ has a $\chi^2$ distribution with $2n$. degrees of freedom. Will this help?

Comment: Yes. And do you know what happens when you multiply gamma by a constant $1/n$? Or when you take the inverse of a random variable with a gamma distribution?

Comment: not sure....could you help on this?

Comment: I could help, but I think I have given enough direction to finish the problem. No need to make it into a $\chi ^2$

Comment: When you say "multiply gamma by a constant 1/n, why is 1/n since n is in the numerator? ...Also, is $$\frac{-1}{\sum_{i=1}^n ln(X_i)}$$ or just $\sum_{i=1}^n ln(X_i)$a gamma distribution?

Comment: Right, you could invert it then multiply by n, or multiply by 1/n then invert

Comment: The inverse of a gamma is also a standard result.

Comment: will still be a gamma distribution. isn't it?

Comment: No. The inverse of a gamma is not a gamma, though the name of the distribution does have the word gamma in it

Comment: is it something I have to show with a lot of math or it is just some well-known fact?

Comment: There's barely any math necessary to perform the transformation and derive the distribution. It's called an inverse gamma, or an inverted gamma. you can find the mean and variance on wikipedia. I hope I have provided you with sufficient assistance. Please remember to upvote and accept if I was helpful!

Comment: so the mean for $\sum_{i=1}^n ln(x_i)$ is n/$\theta$?

Comment: Correct. But be careful because the mean of the inverse will not be one over the mean

Comment: you mean $\frac{-n}{\sum_{i=1} ln(x_i)}$ will not be $\frac{-n}{n/\theta}$?

Comment: Correct.  In general, as a result of jensen's inequality, $E(1/X) \neq 1/E(X)$

Comment: so, how can I find $ E[\frac{-n}{\sum_{i=1}^n ln(x_i)}]$?

Comment: Let $Y = -n/\sum ln(x_i)$.  Then derive the distribution of $Y$ to be an inverse gamma.  Then use standard results about the mean of an inverse gamma.

Comment: If we derive the distribution of Y, is it going to be $$E[\frac{-n}{\sum_{i=1}^n ln(X_i)}] = -n/x [ \frac{(1/\theta)^n}{\Gamma(n)} x^{-n-1} e^{\frac{-1}{\theta x}}]$$?

Comment: No, that doesn't look quite right.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution)

Comment: This is what I follow ... i first take out -n, then multiply by 1/x since we are dealing with expected value. Then, $\alpha= n$, and $\beta = 1/\theta$...so the inside the [...] is just the pdf of invert of gamma distribution. what's wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not follow what you are saying and will not be available for the next 6 hours.  I hope that you are able to work through the details with the help of the link I sent you. Please let me know if you still end up requiring assistance.

Comment: I am still struck. Could you let me know which part of my answer you do you follow?

Comment: It looks like you were trying to find the expectation instead of deriving the distribution of Y. You can do this problem either way.

Comment: is my setup for finding expectation correct then? Which way is easier?

Comment: If you already know that if $X \sim $ gamma implies $1/X \sim$ Inverse Gamma, then the problem is basically done because Inverse Gamma is a well-known distribution and you can look up the mean on the link I posted.

Comment: $\alpha = n$ and $\beta = 1/\theta$, right?

Comment: Careful, you're getting close though.  What were the parameters for the distribution of $-\sum log(X_i)$?

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ since this is gamma distribution?

Comment: Yes, $alpha=n$ and $\beta = 1/\theta$?, right?  So what is the distribution of $- \sum log(X_i) / n$

Comment: I am thinking if $E[\hat{\theta}]$ not equal to $\theta$. Then, there is bias. If they are equal, no bias exists. Do we still need to care the distribution (or I do not know what you are referring to)?

Comment: By the way, what we want to show is $E[-n/\sum log(X_i)]$ right?

Comment: You are correct that it is biased.  And so you know that $-1/\sum log(X_i)$ is inverse gamma with $\alpha=n$ and $\beta=1/\theta$, right?

Comment: So what is $E( - 1/\sum log(X_i))$?

Comment: $\frac{1/\theta}{n-1}$?

Comment: Hmm, close use $\alpha=n$ and $\beta=\theta$.

Comment: is it because we use inverse of gamma distribution...so we use $\beta = \theta$ instead of $1/\theta$?

Comment: No, the parameterization just gets confusing because there are two definitions of gamma which results in different expressions for the mean.

Comment: wait a minute: $log(X_i)$ has an exponential distribution with mean $1/θ$. Can you explain why $\beta = \theta$ instead of $1/\theta$?

Comment: Depending on the parameterization the mean of a gamma is either $\alpha/\beta$ or $\alpha*\beta$

Comment: is it possible to not use the property of mean for the inverse of gamma distribution and just use gamma distribution mean property?

Comment: Yes, you should get $\theta/(n-1)$ for $E( -1/ \sum log(X_i))$, and thus $n*\theta/(n-1)$ for $E( -n / \sum log(X_i))$.

Comment: $E[-n/\sum log (X_i)] = \frac{-n}{n-1} \theta$??

Comment: No, $n\theta / (n-1)$.  Careful of the negative sign.

Comment: why it disappears?

Comment: It doesn't!  $-\sum log(X_i)$ has a gamma distribution.

Comment: The negative sign is part of the transformation!

Comment: that's true...to sum up...when we focus on inverse gamma distribution, $\alpha = n$ and $\beta = \theta$...so we use the property of mean $\frac{\beta}{\alpha-1}$...which gives us  so $E[-1/\sum log (X_i)] = \theta/(n-1)$? And therefore, $E[-n/\sum log (X_i)] = \frac{n}{n-1} \theta$? But for the use of gamma distribution only, we set $\alpha = n$ and $\beta = 1/\theta$, right?...if so, we use the property of mean $\beta\alpha$...which gives us  so $E[-\sum log (X_i)] = 1/\theta (n)$? And therefore, $E[-n/\sum log (X_i)] =  \theta$?...Why the two approaches give different results?

Comment: This completely depends on your definition of gamma!  Look at the two definitions [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution).  Look at the two definitions of the pdf.

Comment: Based on my answer above, which one is correct, then?

Comment: whoa, wait a sec.  You have to pay attention to the details.  $E(1/X)$ DOES NOT EQUAL $1/E(X)$!!!!

Comment: that means I cannot use the gamma distribution only approach right>

Comment: YOU CAN USE THE GAMMA APPROACH, but you CANNOT claim that $ E(-1/\sum log(X_i)) = 1/E(-\sum log(X_i))$  THIS IS NOT TRUE BECAUSE OF JENSEN'S INEQUALITY

Comment: so if I want to use gamma approach, what should I do?

Comment: Learn how to take expectations by pulling out the appropriate constant and formulate the kernel of the appropriate gamma distribution when you integerate.

Comment: you lost me here! but let nail down the bias here: the bias will be (n-1)/n, right?

Comment: bias is generally defined by $E(\hat{\theta}-\theta ) = E(\hat{\theta})- \theta = n\theta/(n-1)- \theta $.  I leave the algebra for you.

Comment: $\theta/(n+1) $ is what you got?

Comment: $\frac{n\theta}{n-1} - \theta = \frac{ n\theta - (n-1)\theta}{n-1} = \theta/(n-1)$

Comment: I'm very sorry you are having so much trouble with this work.  I sincerely hope that you are able to pick up the necessary skills you need and pass your class.

Comment: Sure I will do it. I have several details I still have questions. Let go back to the "Learn how to take expectations by pulling ....when you integrate" ... can you elaborate on it?

Comment: also, I am still a little confused by why $\alpha = n$

Comment: Meanwhile, I have a similar question listed below. If you would like to help out with this, I will appreciate it. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792554/find-the-pdf-of-prod-i-1n-x-i-where-x-is-are-independent-uniform-0-1

Comment: Since $-log(X_i) \sim exp(1/\theta)$ so that $E(-log(X_i)) = 1/\theta$, you get $-\sum log(X_i) \sim gamma( n, 1/\theta)$ where $E(-\sum log(X_i)) = n/\theta$

Comment: With this result I just gave you for the sum of iid exponentials, you should be able to do your other problem as well!

Comment: For the question i have on other post, after $\sum -ln(X_i)$ it should be a Gamma(n,1), right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: how to convert that back to the $\prod X_i$ uniform independent random variables

Comment: transformation.  Define $Y = \sum log(X_i) = log( \prod X_i)$.  Then perform the transformation $e^Y$

Comment: Recall the rule that $e^{log(X)} = X$

Comment: how does this relates to the pdf for Y which is $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\Gamma n} y^{n-1} e^{-y} dy$?

Comment: should I $$e^{this pdf}$$?

Comment: Define $Z=e^Y$ and find the distribution of $Z$.  Notice that the distribution of $Z$ is the distribution of $\prod X_i$.

Comment: i know. this is my question how can I get my pdf for Y to find Z? or I do not need pdf for Y?

Comment: Surely your teacher went over how to find the pdf for a transformation?

Comment: I know . it is weird to exponentiate a pdf for Y to Z? or this is a wrong approach?

Comment: You exponentiate a random variable.  You don't exponentiate the pdf.

Comment: You should post this as a separate question.  Say you have the pdf for Y which is gamma and you want to find the pdf for $e^Y$

Comment: the pdf for Z is $$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma (n)} ln(z)^{n-1} \frac{1}{z^2} dz$$?

Comment: I create a new post link listed below:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794181/the-pdf-for-y-which-is-gamma-and-how-to-find-the-pdf-for-z-ey